# ¿Cómo hacer que un *ActionEvent* se repita aun sin pulsar el botón?

Tags: java, java-swing

Intento crear un *encriptador* que desordene las letras introducidas en un
cuadro de texto.

He creado varias ventanas: una para introducir el texto, 
otra que lo lee y codifica, y otra para mostrar el texto codificado.
El problema surge en la segunda ventana: debería activar un botón, en un principio desactivado, una vez terminada la codificación, letra por letra, del texto introducido, para lo que usa un *bucle while*. Pero el botón nunca se activa... me gustaría saber si es porque el *bucle while* no se ejecuta, ya que es una instancia de otra clase, o la razón concreta de porque falla el código...

Código:

```
package encriptador;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

class Encriptador extends JPanel {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static boolean terminado;
    static Image fondo;
    static JButton encriptar;
    static JLabel texto = new JLabel();
    static JTextField cuadro = new JTextField(50);
    static String introducido;
    static String paso_intermedio;
    static String paso_intermedio2;
    static String encriptado;
    static String encriptado2;
    static boolean empezar;
    static int recopilador;
    static int lector = 1;
    static boolean scaneado;

    /**
     * Construct
     * 
     */
    public Encriptador() {

        File direccion = new File( "wp-1482964256190.jpeg" );
        setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, 2 ));
        try {
            fondo = ImageIO.read( direccion );
            encriptar = new JButton( "desencriptar" );

        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            System.err.println( e.toString( ));
        }

        this.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, 1 ));
        JPanel pantalla_derecha_12 = new JPanel();
        JPanel pantalla_derecha_13 = new JPanel();
        ActionListener desencriptar2 = new Encriptar();
        pantalla_derecha_12.setLayout( new FlowLayout( ));
        pantalla_derecha_13.setLayout( new FlowLayout( ));
        encriptar.addActionListener(desencriptar2);
        pantalla_derecha_12.add(texto);
        pantalla_derecha_12.add(encriptar);
        pantalla_derecha_12.add(cuadro);
        pantalla_derecha_12.setOpaque( false );
        pantalla_derecha_13.setOpaque( false );
        add(pantalla_derecha_13);
        add(pantalla_derecha_12);
    }

    //la segunda ventana donde surge el problema

    class Procesando extends JFrame {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * Construct
         * 
         */
        public Procesando() {
            super();
            setBounds(
                getWidth(), 
                getHeight(), 
                100, 
                200
            );
            PantallaProcesador PP = new PantallaProcesador();
            add( PP );
        }


        class PantallaProcesador extends JPanel {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            JButton continuar = new JButton( "Continuar" );

            /**
             * Construct
             * 
             */
            public PantallaProcesador() {
                super();
                setLayout( new GridLayout(2, 1));
                JPanel x1 = new JPanel();
                JPanel x2 = new JPanel();
                x1.setLayout( new FlowLayout( ));
                x2.setLayout( new FlowLayout( ));
                JLabel xxx = new JLabel("espere por favor");
                x1.add(xxx);
                x2.add(continuar);
                add(x1);
                add(x2);
                ActionListener t = new Traductor();
                continuar.addActionListener(t);
                continuar.setEnabled(scaneado);
            }

            class Procesandos {

                /**
                 * Construct
                 * 
                 */
                public Procesandos() {
                    while ( scaneado = false ) {
                        System.out.println( "n" );

                        introducido = cuadro.getText();
                        recopilador = introducido.length();

                        while ( lector < recopilador ) {
                            lector++;
                            System.out.println( "Número de veces" );

                            paso_intermedio = introducido.substring( lector, lector + 1 );
                            if ( "q".equals( paso_intermedio )) {
                                if ( empezar = false ) {
                                    encriptado = ( "m" );
                                    paso_intermedio2 = encriptado;
                                    encriptado2 = paso_intermedio2;
                                    empezar = true;

                                } else {
                                    encriptado = (paso_intermedio2 + "m");
                                    paso_intermedio2 = encriptado;
                                    encriptado2 = paso_intermedio2;
                                }
                            }

                            //aqui simplemente repido el mismo codigo de arriba pero 
                            //con todas las letras
                        }
                        //una vez salido del bucle while, scaneado es igual a true, 
                        //por lo que el boton deberia activarse

                       scaneado = true;
                    }
                }

            } //class
        }

        class Traductor implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent arg0 ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, encriptado2 );
            }

        } //class
    } //class
} //class
```

Comment: Falta código, esto habría que ejecutarlo. Concretamente he llegado a la línea: **ActionListener desencriptar2 = new encriptar();** y falta la clase que tratas de instanciar.

Answer (score 1):

Como  no sabes cuánto va a tardar el procesado de la cadena de texto que introduce el usuario al codificarse, te sugiero que crees una hebra que se ejecute de forma independiente.
Esto lo puedes conseguir haciendo uso de la interfaz `Runnable`. Utiliza esta hebra para realizar todo el procesado de datos (tu bucle `while` o lo que consideres oportuno) y, una vez terminada la ejecución de esta hebra, activas el botón que comentas.
Te recomiendo que en vez de un `boolean`, definas el botón como `public static` para poder acceder a él desde la hebra y activarlo cuando esta acabe. Esta sería una posible solución:

```
public class Procesar implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // código que procesa el dato que el usuario ha introducido aquí
        Main.boton.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

(Ver Javadoc de la interfaz `Runnable` [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)).

Una vez que hayas hecho esto, simplemente tendrás que crear la hebra y pasarle una instancia de la clase que implementa la interfaz `Runnable`:

```
public class Main {

    public static JButton boton;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        boton = new JButton("Púlsame");
        boton.setEnabled(false);
        // ...
        Procesar procesar = new Procesar();
        Thread t = new Thread(procesar);
        t.start();
    }    
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude con tu problema. No he podido adaptar tu código exacto ya que hay partes que no he llegado a comprender del todo. Pero si necesitas más información, pregúntame.